# Find Sum of 2d Array in Javascript row wise and column wise

Tags: javascript

i want to sum of Array like this

1  1  2 =4

2  2  1 =5

3  3  1 =7

=  =  =

6  6  4

i want to print like this sum of Array Using java script in html.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The rows should be pretty simple, and the columns wouldn't be much harder...

Comment: Is this any homework for you

Comment: It should just take a couple of nested for loops, one which iterates through each cell in each row and one which iterates through each cell in each column.

Comment: arr = new Array(3)
arr[0]= new Array(3)
arr[1]= new Array(3)
arr[2]= new Array(3)
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
n= prompt("number",0)
arr[i][j]=n                                                                                              
 }  
}
document.write("array elements and row/column wise sum:"+"<br>")
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
var sum=0; 
   for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
   sum=sum + eval(arr[i][j]);
document.write (arr[i][j]+"   ") 
 }
document.write(sum+"<br>")
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
var sum=0;  
   for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
   sum=sum + eval(arr[j][i]);
 }
document.write(sum+" " )
}

Comment: i did this lolz no need to solve ;)

Comment: @dilshad, that's a pretty crude solution.

Comment: @dilshad Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your solution as an answer to your own question, rather than as a comment. This makes it clearer for others that will view this question in the future, and allows your answer to be voted up/down and compared to other answers that may be given. You can also accept your own answer if it's the best one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start by breaking the problem down into smaller pieces first. I defined a basic `sum` function which is defined using an even more basic `add` function. `map`ping `sum` over the input array will give you the horizontal sums.

The vertical sums are little more tricky, but not too tough. I defined a `transpose` function which rotate our matrix. Once we rotate, we can `sum` the rows the same way.

This solution works on any *MxN* matrix

```js
// generic, reusable functions
const add = (x,y) => x + y
const sum = xs => xs.reduce(add, 0)
const head = ([x,...xs]) => x
const tail = ([x,...xs]) => xs

const transpose = ([xs, ...xxs]) => {
  const aux = ([x,...xs]) =>
    x === undefined
      ? transpose (xxs)
      : [ [x, ...xxs.map(head)], ...transpose ([xs, ...xxs.map(tail)])]
  return xs === undefined ? [] : aux(xs)
}

// sample data
let numbers = [
  [1,1,1],
  [2,2,2],
  [3,3,3],
  [4,4,4]
]

// rows
console.log(numbers.map(sum))
// [ 3, 6, 9, 12 ]

// columns
console.log(transpose(numbers).map(sum))
// [ 10, 10, 10 ]
```

Comment: Thanks but i get other way to solve it

Comment: @dilshad, yeah I see that, but the for loop solution is as crude as markings on a cave wall.

Comment: I know OP asked for a certain scenario, But your code works only for NxN array.

Comment: @naomik try: `numbers = [
  [1,1,2],
  [2,2,1],
  [3,3,1],
  [5,4,3]
]`
. cols will result: `[11, 10, 7, NaN]`

Comment: @naomik `let cols = numbers[0].map((_, i) => sum(numbers.map(index(i))))` should work.

Comment: @A.Akram ah you're right. I overlooked that. I reworked this answer to support MxN arrays

Comment: @A.Akram note, i didn't use `numbers[0]` to ensure that vertical sums would work even if `[]` was given as an input.