# Javascript - Summing each element of an array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array:

```
var array1 = [ [1, 2, 3], [7, 9, 2], [6, 8, 1] ]
```

I want the output to be:

```
var array2 = [ 14, 19, 6 ]

array1[0] = 1 + 7 + 6
array1[1] = 2 + 9 + 8
array1[2] = 3 + 2 + 1
```

How can I sum each element of an array by index?

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Use nested loops.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not tried anything before asking question.

Comment: Can close the sum response of the square matrix by both the line (horizontal sum) and the column (vertical sum) are on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079503/find-sum-of-2d-array-in-javascript-row-wise-and-column-wise

Comment: In the link above the staff was more proactive than just giving negative in the question. And the person who created the question wrote little too. The same problem written in a different way helps other people to find their answers, which strengthens the Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var array1 = [ [1, 2, 3], [7, 9, 2], [6, 8, 1] ]
var array2 = [ [4, 5, 6], [2, 6, 12], [10, 10, 10] ]


function sumByIndex(arr) {
    return arr.map( (item, idx) => {
        return arr.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr[idx] , 0 )
    })
}


sumByIndex(array1)
//[ 14, 19, 6 ]


sumByIndex(array2)
//[ 16, 21, 28 ]
```

Comment: Let the OP try something first. Asking for help, without trying anything should be discouraged.